# In F#, how to instantiate a generic type definition?

Tags: f#

How can I instantiate a generic type **definition** in F#? (i.e. an instance of Type class whose IsGenericTypeDefinition property returns true).

Example in C#:

```
Type d1 = typeof(Dictionary<,>);
```

Note:

```
typeof<Dictionary<'T,'U>>
```

does not work. 'T and 'U are interpreted as object.

Comment: [`typedefof<'T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.typedefof%5B%27t%5D-type-function-%5Bfsharp%5D), I think.

Comment: @ildjarn I already tried 'T. It does not work because 'T is interpreted as object. Updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let t = typedefof<Dictionary<_,_>>
t.IsGenericTypeDefinition // true
```

This is not the same as `typeof`. Note the `def` in the middle :)